# Usage of temp table T-SQL vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I am familiar with long T-SQL that use several temp tables. Now I am trying to learn how to do the same in MySQL, but I can't find a way to use the temp table I've created.

If I execute this in **SQL Server** it works:

```
SELECT ID, name, distance 
INTO #temp_table
FROM table00 
WHERE ID > 001

SELECT *
FROM #temp_table
WHERE distance < 450
```

but if I execute this in **MySQL** (phpMyAdmin) I get an error:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS (SELECT ID, name, distance FROM table00 WHERE ID > 001)

SELECT *
FROM temp_table
WHERE distance < 450
```

Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT * FROM temp_table' at line 3

Where is the problem in this MySQL code?

MySQL version: *5.0.92-enterprise-gpl-log*

Comment: You are just missing a `;`

Comment: That's two MySQL statements. They need a separator.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks! That was the problem, now it works!